# How do I determine sufficient conditions for the existence of the solution of an initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Suppose that $f$ is a smooth function from $\mathbb R^{3}$ to $\mathbb R$ with $f(0,0,0)=0$. Under what sufficient condition will the differential equation $f(x,y,y')$ have a solution satisfying the initial condition $y(0)=0$ in a neighborhood of $0$ ?
Please help.